# How to query status of celery task

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

With this code, is it possible to query the worker `state` whether it is in `state`=1 or `state`=2?

```
from celery import Celery
import time

#celery -A CeleryTask worker --loglevel=info

app = Celery("CeleryTask", backend="redis://localhost", broker="redis://localhost")


@app.task
def train():
    for i in range(100):
        if i<5:
            state=1

        else:
            state=2
        time.sleep(10)

    return "hallo"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = train.delay()
```

Answer (score 1):

Celery, being awesome as it is, provides you with mechanism to create your own [custom states](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html#custom-states) and update them using the *update_state()* method.

From the (linked) documentation:

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def upload_files(self, filenames):
    for i, file in enumerate(filenames):
        if not self.request.called_directly:
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',
                meta={'current': i, 'total': len(filenames)})
```

In your case, all you have to do is call update_state() with `meta={"state":X}` where X is 1 or 2...